# Pass touches from a UIView to UIScrollView beneath it

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` stretching over the entire screen, which the user is able to scroll vertically only. Right 'above' it is a `UIView` with a few buttons, which covers the bottom 120 px only. The user may tap the buttons to invoke their selectors. But I wish to be able to pass the panning movement to the scrollView, so that the user may scroll the scrollView if they pan with a velocity greater than a certain threshold, if the panning begins over the `UIView`.

How would I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: You can go with UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

Comment: I suggest you add that view to scrollView and when scroll or drag will happen ,set view's frame such that it always will be at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things.

1. Add a `UITouchesMoved` function to your uiView, calculate finger movement and move your scrollView accordingly by scrolling it to a `CGPoint`.
2. You can use UIPanGestureRecognizer.